# Migrating to Bing Geo location (Phase 2) returns old API response

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to migrate to Phase 2 of the Bing Geo Migration according to the latest API changes: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/advertising-targeting/bing-geo-migration-guide?trk=eml-mktg-20191028-developer-email-api-updates-october&mcid=6592215409070530560&src=e-eml#migration-phase-2-use-bing-geo-location-in-ad-campaigns

As mentioned in the documentation, the Typeahead API will ONLY return Bing locations as of 12/12/2019 but I keep getting the legacy location response.

Endpoint:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adTargetingEntities?q=TYPEAHEAD&facet=urn:li:adTargetingFacet:locations&query=afri
```

Response:

```
"elements": [
    {
        "urn": "urn:li:countryGroup:AF",
        "facetUrn": "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:locations",
        "name": "Africa"
    },
    {
        "urn": "urn:li:country:za",
        "facetUrn": "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:locations",
        "name": "South Africa"
    }
]
```

What changes should I make in the endpoint in order to retrieve the following response which includes the Bing Geo Location:

```
"elements": [
    {
        "urn": "urn:li:geo:103537801",
        "facetUrn": "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:locations",
        "name": "Africa"
    },
    {
        "urn": "urn:li:geo:104035573",
        "facetUrn": "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:locations",
        "name": "South Africa"
    }
]
```